# problem in changing matrix to a data frame with same dimensions

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have tried to create a data frame from a matrix; however, the result has a different dimension comparing to the main matrix. Please see below my code:

```
out <- table(UL_Final$Issue_Year, UL_Final$Insured_Age_Group)
out <- out/rowSums(out)  #changing all numbers to ratio
```

The result is a matrix 12 by 7:

```
              1           2           3           4           5           6           7
  1387 0.165137615 0.036697248 0.229357798 0.321100917 0.201834862 0.018348624 0.027522936
  1388 0.149222065 0.110325318 0.197312588 0.342291372 0.136492221 0.055162659 0.009193777
  1389 0.144979508 0.101946721 0.222848361 0.335553279 0.138575820 0.046362705 0.009733607
  1390 0.146991622 0.120030465 0.191622239 0.336024372 0.142269612 0.052551409 0.010510282
  1391 0.165462754 0.111794582 0.185835214 0.321049661 0.135553047 0.064503386 0.015801354
  1392 0.162399144 0.109583402 0.165321917 0.317388441 0.146344476 0.076115594 0.022847028
  1393 0.181602139 0.116447173 0.151104070 0.325131201 0.148628577 0.062778493 0.014308347
  1394 0.163760504 0.098529412 0.142489496 0.323792017 0.178728992 0.076050420 0.016649160
  1395 0.137097032 0.094699511 0.128981757 0.321320170 0.197610147 0.098245950 0.022045433
  1396 0.167187958 0.103851041 0.112696706 0.293202033 0.200689082 0.099306031 0.023067149
  1397 0.193250090 0.130540713 0.108114843 0.270743930 0.186411584 0.091364656 0.019574185
  1398 0.208026156 0.147573562 0.100455157 0.249503173 0.191935380 0.083338676 0.019167895
```

then using the code below:

```
out <- data.frame(out)
```

However, the result will change to a data frame and dimension of 84 by 3

```
   Var1 Var2        Freq
1  1387    1 0.165137615
2  1388    1 0.149222065
3  1389    1 0.144979508
4  1390    1 0.146991622
5   ....     .......
```

I am not sure why this happens. However in another case, as I explained below, I am not seeing such strange behavior. In another case, I used the code below to calculate another ratio for another variable:

```
out <- table( df_select$Insured_Age_Group,df_select$Policy_Status)
out <- cbind(out, Ratio = out[,2]/rowSums(out))
```

the result is :

```
  Issuance Surrended     Ratio
1    31046      5735 0.1559229
2    20039      4409 0.1803420
3    20399      9228 0.3114726
4    48677     17216 0.2612721
5    30045      8132 0.2130078
6    13947      4106 0.2274414
7     3157      1047 0.2490485
```

Now if we used the code below (by @Ronak Shah):

```
out <- data.frame(out) %>% mutate(x = row_number())
```

the result is :

```
  Issuance Surrended     Ratio x
1    31046      5735 0.1559229 1
2    20039      4409 0.1803420 2
3    20399      9228 0.3114726 3
4    48677     17216 0.2612721 4
5    30045      8132 0.2130078 5
6    13947      4106 0.2274414 6
7     3157      1047 0.2490485 7
```

As you can see the result is now a data frame with same dimension. Can anyone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `?table` for an explanation:

> The `as.data.frame` method for objects inheriting from class "table" can be used to convert the array-based representation of a contingency table to **a data frame containing the classifying factors and the corresponding entries** (the latter as component named by responseName). This is the inverse of xtabs.

A workaround is to use `as.data.frame.matrix`:

```
m <- table(mtcars$carb, mtcars$gear)
as.data.frame(m)
#    Var1 Var2 Freq
# 1     1    3    3
# 2     2    3    4
# 3     3    3    3
# 4     4    3    5
# 5     6    3    0
# 6     8    3    0
# 7     1    4    4
# 8     2    4    4
# 9     3    4    0
# 10    4    4    4
# 11    6    4    0
# 12    8    4    0
# 13    1    5    0
# 14    2    5    2
# 15    3    5    0
# 16    4    5    1
# 17    6    5    1
# 18    8    5    1
as.data.frame.matrix(m)
#   3 4 5
# 1 3 4 0
# 2 4 4 2
# 3 3 0 0
# 4 5 4 1
# 6 0 0 1
# 8 0 0 1
```